# How to bind to a directive attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want the title for the highchart to be `$scope.data.title` but currently the attribute title interpret `data.title` as a string and a bind to the scope. I've tried putting `"", {{}}` around data.title the .html but it doesn't work. I think im missing something else.

**index.html**

```
  <test-chart title="{{data.title}}">
    <chart-series title="Series 1" type="line">
    </chart-series>
    <chart-series title="Series 3" type="column">
    </chart-series>
  </test-chart>
```

**script.js**

```
  .directive('testChart', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      controllerAs:'chartCtrl',
      scope: {
      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.data = {
            title: 'HIGHGRAPH',
            series: [{
                title: 'series1', 
                type: 'line', 
                data: [1,2]
            }, {
                title: 'series2', 
                type: 'area', 
                data: [3,5]
            }]
        }        

    var hc = Highcharts.chart('highchart_container', {}); 

    $scope.$watch("data",function(newValue,oldValue) {

      hc.update({
         title: {
              text: newValue.title
            }
      })
    })

        this.addSeries = function(a) {

          hc.addSeries({
            name: a.title,
            type: a.type,
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          })
        };
      }],
      templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
    };
```

**EDIT**: https://plnkr.co/edit/spUAkCjK61HgUGu40pZl?p=preview

This not works as intended, but is it possible to do it without the `watch`?

Comment: Why don't you do `title: { text: $scope.data.title }`?

Comment: @devqon I didnt try if your answer will work. But bad solution

Comment: @devqon I could do that if I only want to set the title using the object I set in the scope, but I don't want that.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho try my answer plz

Comment: I really don't get why do you want to pass it in attribute because you already got that in the directive as @devqon want to say. If something is wanted to pass in attribut , it's because we would put something static from view eg: title="This is not dynamic", and for you code it's fine with that.

Comment: Its just an example, I don't want the title to be static.

Answer (score 4):

you won't have to put s.title inside ng-repeat. it should be outside.
Here is a working snippet.:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
});

app.directive('testChart', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      controllerAs:'chartCtrl',
      scope: {
      },    
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        
     $scope.data = {
         title: 'HIGHGRAPH',
            series: [{
             title: 'series1', 
                type: 'line', 
                data: [1,2]
            }, {
             title: 'series2', 
             type: 'area', 
             data: [3,5]
            }]
        }        

        var hc = Highcharts.chart('highchart_container', {
          title: {
            text: $scope.data.title
          }
        });

        this.addSeries = function(a) {
          
          hc.addSeries({
            name: a.title,
            type: a.type,
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          })
        };
      }],
      template: '<div> <p>This is a chart</p><ul> <li ng-repeat="s in series">  </li> </ul> <div id=\'highchart_container\'></div> <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> </div>'
    };
  })
  .directive('chartSeries', function() {
    return {
      require: '^test-chart',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, chartCtrl) {
        chartCtrl.addSeries(attrs);
      },
    };
  });
```

```css
#highchart_container{
height:250px!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <test-chart title="Custom title">
    <chart-series title="Series 1" type="line">
    </chart-series>
    <chart-series title="Series 3" type="column">
    </chart-series>
  </test-chart>

</div>
```

Comment: you put the title outside of the highchart object.I want `text: $attrs.title` to be set. I also notice `$attrs.title` has the "HIGHGRAPH" value in it, but the value sets before the `$attrs` sets. So if I add a watch on data I can get `text: $attrs.title` to be set with the correct value.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho i have updated my anwer. check if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is how you must do it. Highchart docs for [title](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title)

working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yp7fjP2wK7ZqB87iXORW?p=preview)

Now **my-tabs.html**

```
<div>
  <div id='highchart_container'></div>
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

and **index.html**

```
<body ng-app="docsTabsExample">
  <test-chart>

    <chart-series title="Series 1" type="line">
    </chart-series>
    <chart-series title="Series 3" type="column">
    </chart-series>
  </test-chart>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
  .directive('testChart', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      controllerAs:'chartCtrl',
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.data = {
            title: 'HIGHGRAPH',
              series: [{
                title: 'series1', 
                  type: 'line', 
                  data: [1,2]
              }, {
                title: 'series2', 
                type: 'area', 
                data: [3,5]
              }]
          }  

        var hc = Highcharts.chart('highchart_container', {
          title: {
            align:"center",
            text:$scope.data.title
          }
        }); 


        this.addSeries = function(a) {

          hc.addSeries({
            name: a.title,
            type: a.type,
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          })
        };
      }],
      templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
    };
  })
  .directive('chartSeries', function() {
    return {
      require: '^test-chart',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, chartCtrl) {
        chartCtrl.addSeries(attrs);
      },
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: In the exampe you have there is no highchart title.

Comment: its in div- inside the template. you get it throughout the the directive. When u hover over the directive u see the title. see the plunker

Comment: @PresidentCamacho This is exactly what you wanted right?

Comment: I want something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/mBLRZYXRk5kNXcawc8T8?p=preview but without the watch. Is it possible?

Comment: Difference being??

Comment: I've now set the value from $scope.data.title as a title for the highchart. I had to add `watch` on the data object to get it to set.

Comment: are you speaking about the title you see on hover or the title as on header?

Comment: title as highchart title. I've removed the html title to not confuse.

Comment: Why dont you bind like my answer **my-tabs.html** now

Comment: @PresidentCamacho also check the current plunker

Comment: Did you see my updated plunker? Also did you forget to update yours? I've removed all my code from **my-tabs.html**. The only title I want to set is the one in the highchart.

Comment: Ok. You want to set it from inside of highchart?

Comment: yes, see my example. But I already did that, The question is now if its required to have the watch or is it possible to do it in another way?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho now is it fine?

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but thats not the point of this quesiton. I want to decide If I want to have a title or not by the having the binding in `index.html` or not  `<test-chart title="{{data.title}}">`. I've actually already solved my own question. The queston now is if theres a way to bypass the `watch` or not. But my binding is currently correct.

Comment: Did you not see me bypass the watch? check the latest answer now?  I dont know a lot a bout highcharts but does it not handle title change event?

Comment: Yes you bypassed the watch, but you also bypassed the directive-attribute binding which was the whole point of this question. I thank you for helping, but I think I'm content with my current solution.

Comment: dude. If your purpose is to discuss and learn directive attribute binding, create a custom directive which is not using a library to show the control. The actual way to pass data to a external library control is the way they suggest. if you pass the config varibales as an object, it should work as you change it.

Comment: I understand your frustration and if I could choose I would've done it as you suggested. Currently im adding an extra layer of structure to my already defined $scope.data. Which is unnecassary.But's how they want it.

Comment: I let it go dude.Take it easy

Answer (score 1):

i can't see why you need data binding if the title is a scope variable of the chartCtrl.

this will simply do the trick:

```
<div>
    {{data.title}}
   <div id='highchart_container'></div>
   <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yvdtau62LzlDfh3cpHB9?p=preview)

Comment: Because I want the title to be set in highchart.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho check my updated answer. I looked into highchart docs and found how to do it

Comment: @JinsPeter perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a `watch` on the object.

https://plnkr.co/edit/spUAkCjK61HgUGu40pZl?p=preview

Comment: did you check out @Jins Peter answer. I think it's the right solution.

Comment: @dev yes I did, both got my goal right, but its the not the way I want it to be set. $scope.data is only temporary. The directive is static and the index.htm will be not.

Comment: Advice: unwanted watchers can decrease the performance of your application.